# how many orders displaying based on Selected From & To Date

Tags: magento-1.9, database, orders

we are using below code to filter orders based on selected From & To date.

we can able to filter successfully & displaying results on custom page [orders.php].

[image]

**php**

```
function getDesignerCollection()
    {
        /* date search */
        if (isset($_POST['post_at']) && $_POST['post_at'] != '')
            {
            $orderFromDate = $_POST['post_at'] . " 00:00:00 ";

            }
            else
            {
            $orderFromDate = '';
            }

        if (isset($_POST['post_at_to_date']) && $_POST['post_at_to_date'] != '')
            {
            $orderToDate = $_POST['post_at_to_date'] . "    23:59:59  ";

            }
            else
            {
            $orderToDate = '';
            }
       /* date search end*/

        $accountType = $rows['type'];
        if ($accountType == "admin")
            {

            if ($orderFromDate != '') $order->addFieldToFilter('created_at', array(
                'gteq' => $orderFromDate
            ));
            if ($orderToDate != '') $order->addFieldToFilter('created_at', array(
                'lteq' => $orderToDate
            ));
            }
```

**form**

```
<form name="frmSearch" method="post" action="">

    <input type="text"  id="post_at" value="" name="post_at"  />  
    <input type="text" id="post_at_to_date" value=""name="post_at_to_date"  />

    <input type="submit" name="search" value="search" id="searchButton">

    </form>
```

now we want to display **count of how many rows are displayed.**  so we tried below code. its displaying like below image. its displaying **"rows = 3"**. because its considering "entity_id" column of **"sales_flat_order"** table.  but i want **"rows : 9"** as you can see 9 rows in image.

[image]

[image]

```
require_once '../../app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();

// specify the date picker date-format
$format = 'Y-m-d';


// if posted data are not empty
if(!empty($_POST['post_at']) && !empty($_POST['post_at_to_date']))
{

       if (!empty($_POST['post_at'])) {
           $dateFrom = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $_POST['post_at']);
       }

       if (!empty($_POST['post_at_to_date'])) {
           $dateTo = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $_POST['post_at_to_date']);
       }

        // Get the resource model
        $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');

       // Retrieve the read connection
          $read = $resource->getConnection('core_read');

      // MySQL query
        $query =  'SELECT entity_id, created_at, dproduct_id FROM sales_flat_order WHERE created_at BETWEEN :fromdate AND :todate ;';

// Bind MySQL parameters
$binds = array(
'fromdate' => $dateFrom->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
'todate' => $dateTo->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')
);
// Execute the query and store the results in $results
$results = $read->fetchAll($query,$binds);
echo "rows : ".count($results);
echo "<br>";
print_r($results);
}


else {
echo "error you have not specified any dates";
}
```

complete code : http://pastebin.com/hMUEusvb

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because even though the code posted included some Magento code this is a PHP/MySQL question and it should be asked on stackoverflow

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism Thanks for your comment, please check updated question, now  this question is related to both magento code & database, if you nominate for `reopening` the question, that will be really helpfull.....

Comment: Sorry but this is still a PHP/MySQL question only like most of the questions you've been asking recently. Please ask them on stackoverflow.com